# TypeError: responder.scrollResponderScrollTo is not a function

Tags: ios, react-native, npm, npm-install

In my React native expo project am facing issues with the IOS simulator and real IOS device. Actually am using React native: "0.65.1", and I tried 64.0, and 65.2 but no use.

The Error is

```
TypeError: responder.scrollResponderScrollTo is not a function. (In 'responder.scrollResponderScrollTo({
        x: x,
        y: y,
        animated: animated
      })', 'responder.scrollResponderScrollTo' is undefined)
```

after spending a few hrs I found out that this issue will come based on 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view' this npm but I haven't used it in my project. So how can we fix this issue

Answer (score 5):

This is an [open GitHub issue for react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view/issues/519).

Suppose that you are using `react-native 0.65.2`, then you can fix this issue by updating [react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view version 0.9.5](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view/releases/tag/v0.9.5).

Comment: Thanks for your response but I haven't used this react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view version 0.9.5. in my project so. My question is why this error comes.

Comment: issue fixed by upgrading to `react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view version 0.9.5`

Answer (score 2):

Update the following code in the */node_modules/@codler/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view/lib/KeyboardAwareHOC.js* file line number 244.

```
scrollToPosition = (x: number, y: number, animated: boolean = true) => {
  const responder = this.getScrollResponder()
  if (!responder) {
    return
  }
  if (responder.scrollResponderScrollTo) {
    // React Native < 0.65
    responder.scrollResponderScrollTo({ x, y, animated })
  } else if (responder.scrollTo) {
    // React Native >= 0.65
    responder.scrollTo({ x, y, animated })
  }
  // responder && responder.scrollResponderScrollTo({ x, y, animated })
}

scrollToEnd = (animated?: boolean = true) => {
  const responder = this.getScrollResponder()
  if (!responder) {
    return
  }
  if (responder.scrollResponderScrollTo) {
    // React Native < 0.65
    responder.scrollResponderScrollTo({ x, y, animated })
  } else if (responder.scrollTo) {
    // React Native >= 0.65
    responder.scrollTo({ x, y, animated })
  }
  // responder && responder.scrollResponderScrollToEnd({ animated })
}
```

Comment: This was a useful answer. I don't normally patch packages, but this patch proved helpful in one of my projects.  The [patch-package](https://github.com/ds300/patch-package) node package can help you patch node modules.

Comment: @karthik dorairaj Worked for me! I was use older version of native-base "^2.15.2" with latest react native version "0.72.6". I don't where that codler came from but your answer helped me alot. Thanks